# Javascript recursion in both if and else

Tags: javascript, recursion

First, let me show you what I'm dealing with.
[image]
I am generating graph nodes and relations between them in buildGraphNode function. However, I don't want to generate things I circled in red (those are folders). To determine whether the node is folder or not I have to check if treeNode.data instanceof Array - If its instance then it's a folder and I don't want it in my graph. My function works great if I don't add that if check, but once I add it I'm having problems with what to put in else statement. Here is my code:

```
function buildGraphNode(treeNode){
    var memb;
    var child;
    if(!(treeNode.data instanceof Array)) {
        memb = member("" + treeNode.label, "" + treeNode.icon, '', '#d0000c', '', 'B','\uf16b' );
        members.push(memb);
        for (var i = 0; i < treeNode.children.length; i++) {
            child = buildGraphNode(treeNode.children[i]);
            if (child != null && memb != null) {
                connections.push(link(memb, child));
            }
        }
        return memb;
    }
    else{
        for (var i = 0; i < treeNode.children.length; i++) {
            child = buildGraphNode(treeNode.children[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

This generation does work fine, it generates nodes without folders, but my connections array is empty. It never reaches if (child != null && memb != null) { because child variable is always undefined. Remember when I remove first statement everything is fine. child is properly assigned. Any hints?

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/masterfan/pen/BRNMOg)

Comment: Bit hard to try by just reading it. Is there a way this can be recreated in a jsfiddle or something? Just a JSON structure as input or output would do

Comment: your main function has no return in the else. Create a demo using some basic data, enough to create the basic tree as in [mcve]

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Comment: You need to narrow your problem down so that you don't need the dependencies, as that linked page notes. Please read the links before dismissing the comments.